# Design pattern to handle groups of objects

Tags: c++, oop, object, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class `item`. Each instance of this class is an object in 3D space, can be basic shapes like *cylinder*, *sphere* and *cone*. The `class Item` has a convenient API for **geometry** (radius, top radius, bot radius, length) and **transformations** (rotation, translation, scale).

```cpp
enum ItemType {
    Sphere = 1,
    Cone
}

class Item
{
// ...
public:
    ItemType type();
    void setType(const ItemType &t);

    float radius();
    float length();
    float topRadius();
    float botRadious();
    QMatrix4x4 transformations();

    void setRadius(const float &r);
    void setLength(const float &l);
    void setTopRadius(const float &tr);
    void setBotRadius(const float &br);
    void setTransformations(const QMatrix4x4 &matrix);
// ...
}
```

[image: Class instances as 3D items]

Frequently, I want to glue multiple objects together to form a unified shape. For example, two *spheres* and a *cone* are connected below. The geometry and transformations of the unified object is dependent upon those of two *spheres* and one *cone*.

[image: Three objects]
[image: Three objects unified]

The problem is:

1. Convenient handling of the unified object is not possible
2. By handling, I mean, for example, transforming. Like changing the length of the unified object which requires, changing the length of the middle cone and location of the two spheres accordingly.
3. `class Item` has API for convenient handling of each individual object, but not the unified one
4. For handling of the unified object, I have to work with three different objects which is torturous

The question is:

Which design patterns are best suited to conveniently handle the unified objects?

Comment: Whereas transformation might be applied to any shape. geometry does depend of object type: `radius` doesn't make sense for bounding box or `TopRadius` for Sphere...

Comment: Start by defining a `Group` class that defines an arbitrary reference point (say, the center of mass) and remembers how each `Item` in the group is positioned and rotated relative to this reference point. That already enables rotation, scaling and translation of the group. If you want additional behavior (like stretching the cone along one axis) you will need to designate one of the items as "root" and define how each modification affects the rest of the group.

Comment: @Botje What would the relationship between `Group` class and `Item` class?

Comment: `Group` would contain a collection (`std::vector`, `std::list`, ...) of `Item` instances, each with a translation, rotation and scale relative to the group's reference point.

Comment: @Botje Thanks. Let me try to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This question is about object oriented software design and software patterns, it has nothing to do specifically with C++.  The only part that is C++ specific is the use of the `virtual` keyword, but even that, is just the C++-specific keyword that gives you polymorphism, which is again, an object-oriented principle, not something unique to C++.

So, what you first of all need to do, is to extract a true interface for what you call "API".  I would call this `Primitive3D`, and it would be a `class` containing nothing but pure virtual methods.  (In C++, that would be `virtual function(parameters) = 0`.)

Then, each one of your primitives would be implementing the interface by providing an implementation for each pure virtual method.  If you have some basic functionality that all implementations will share, then in addition to implementing this interface you can also keep a common base class.  However, the introduction of the interface will keep your options more open.

Then, introduce a new primitive, called perhaps `Conglomerate`.  Again, that would be yet one more class implementing `Primitive3D`.  That class would provide its own implementations for setting various attributes like length and transformation, and these implementations would work by setting some of the attributes of contained primitives.

The `Conglomerate` class would also provide a few functions which are specific to it and cannot be found in the `Primitive3D` interface.  You would use these functions to configure the conglomerate, at the very least to populate the conglomerate with its contents.

The function which adds a new member primitive to the conglomerate may accept additional parameters to indicate precisely at which position of the conglomeration the new member should appear, what kind of transformation to perform when scaling the primitive, what kind of transformation to perform when translating the primitive, etc.

Internally, the conglomeration would probably make use of a `vector` containing instances of some internal `member` structure, which would contain a reference to a `Primitive3D` and any other information that is necessary so as to know how to handle that primitive.  Do not make the mistake of adding this information to the `Primitive3D` itself, it does not belong there, because a primitive does not know, and should not know, that it is a member of a conglomeration.  I would even go as far as to say that the *location* of a primitive is not a feature of the primitive itself; it is a feature of the space that contains the primitive, whether this space is the universe, or a conglomeration.

Comment: Up-voted. Thanks :) Let me implement this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your structure, composite is the pattern you should consider. Also identifying concrete shape with 'type' attribute is against object oriented design. It kills polymorphism, a great unique tool available in OO. Composite pattern will allow you to address elements as well as their aggregation in one hiearchy.